# How can i sort my JSON data by value JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have a lot of data like this and i need to sort all data how can i do sort data?

Example

```
[
    {
        "date":159,
        "content":"blablabla"
    },
    {
        "date":null,
        "content":"blablabla"
    },
    {
        "date":7895,
        "content":"blablabla"
    }
]
```

how can i sort like this;

```
[
    {
        "date":null,
        "content":"blablabla"
    },
    {
        "date":159,
        "content":"blablabla"
    }
    {
        "date":7895,
        "content":"blablabla"
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Take a look at [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) however as Jon said, you should provide at least an attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
json.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.date - b.date;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `sort` and since it looks like you're attempting to sort by a date, convert the value into a date object.

```
const data = [
  {
    "date":159,
    "content":"blablabla"
  },
  {
    "date":null,
    "content":"blablabla"
  },
  {
    "date":7895,
    "content":"blablabla"
  }
]

data.sort((a,b) => {
  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
})
```

Comment: No need to turn those values into `Date` objects. Subtracting will turn both operands back into the value you passed to them. (Not to mention that 159 and 7895 seem too small to represent the number of milliseconds since 1970, which the value that is passed to the Date constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the `sort` method and sort after the `date` prop:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
```